# Service changing port when scanned with nmap

Tags: nmap, network-scanners

While scanning a host with nmap I have discovered an unusual service. The service moves to another port everytime I perform an nmap-scan or try to curl it. I have not yet found any info about similar cases, so I am currently not sure how to move forward. Are there any ways I can try to connect to the service, without the service moving to another port?

Comment: Use a script and `curl` to connect to every port.

Comment: @ThoriumBR I forgot to mention that I have already made such a script. The script returns an empty header and body when it reaches the port the service is running on.

Comment: So how you are sure there's a service there?

Comment: @ThoriumBR I am not, I just assumed it as the port was open.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like port knocking. Port knocking is where you connect to a sequence of ports before a port is exposed that allows you to connect to a specific service.

Some people like to use it as an extra security measure to lockdown SSH.

For example lets say I've configured my server to listen on port TCP/1111, then when someone connects to TCP/1111 it will open TCP/2222 and so on until finally port TCP/22 opens and I can SSH to my device.

You can read more about how this works in the below link.

https://www.howtogeek.com/442733/how-to-use-port-knocking-on-linux-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is no pattern in which ports that turns open, which as per my understanding is required for port knocking. Everytime I perform an nmap scan or connect to an open port a completely random port opens up. Could this still be port knocking?